# Left Outer Join Not Showing All Records

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following sql statement

```
SELECT * FROM inventory LEFT OUTER JOIN invUpdate ON (inventory.vin = invUpdate.vin)
```

It is providing me with the correct # of records but only showing information from the invUpdate table. I am using the following php variable

`$row_Recordset1['vin']`

to display the records on a basic web page. While it lists out 103 records down the page, only the 4 records from the invUpdate page actually show. The rest are empty. Do I need to change up my sql statement or should I be using a different variable?

Comment: you should provide a sample data of your two tables, and a sample of your desired result

Comment: Not sure I know how to go about this but I'll give it a try.

Comment: `SHOW COLUMNS FROM \`inventory\`;` and `SHOW COLUMNS FROM \`invUpdate\`;`

Comment: Hi Ben, are those separate sql statements? Not sure I totally follow here.

Comment: IFNULL() is specific to MySQL, the standard SQL alternative is COALESCE() it is also available in MySQL

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is that there are two columns named `vin` returned by the query. And those both get assigned to the same array element `$row['vin']`. I believe that's the crux of the problem you are encountering.

One way to fix that is to ditch the **`SELECT *`** and explicitly list the expressions you want to return.  Since both `inventory` and `invUpdate` tables contain a column named `vin`, both of those are in the list of expressions returned by the `SELECT *`.

If you need to return both, then assign one (or both) of those expressions with an *alias* that differentiates it from the other. For example:

```
SELECT inventory.vin               AS vin
     , inventory.somecol           AS somecol 
     , invUpdate.vin               AS uvin
     , SUBSTR(inventory.foo1,1,1)  AS f
     , ...
  FROM ...
```

After a row is fetched, you can access the values returned by both of the `vin` columns, referencing them by the assigned *alias* (i.e. the column name assigned to the expression.)

```
  $val1 = $row['vin'];
  $val2 = $row['uvin'];
```

This isn't the only approach. But it's the approach I prefer, explicitly listing the expressions I want to return, and explicitly assigning an alias. It's a common pattern used for more complicated expressions in SQL statements. The same pattern works for simple statements too.

**FOLLOWUP**

This goes well beyond the original question that was asked. In response to a comment, about "overriding" values of columns from `inventory` with values of columns from `invUpdate`, when a matching row is found in `invUpdate`...

Personally, if I wanted to do that, I would prefer to do that in the SQL statement. (Others have different opinions, there's room for differing opinions. I'd prefer to have a statement that returns the result I actually want to display, without a lot of extra columns.

Not having any idea of what columns are in your table, (the `SELECT *` doesn't give the poor reader much to go on), assuming that the columns are identically named in the two tables.

Given the join predicate  `vin`=`vin`, we know that `vin` from `invUpdate` cannot be NULL when a matching row is found.

```
  SELECT IF(u.vin IS NULL,i.vin,u.vin) AS vin
```

That expression says, if a matching row was not found in `invUpdate`, return `vin` from the `inventory` table, else return `vin` from `invUpdate` table. That's equivalent to the more ANSI standard compliant:

```
  SELECT CASE WHEN u.VIN IS NULL THEN i.vin ELSE u.vin END AS vin
```

If we want values from *all* of the columns from `invUpdate` to "override" values from all of the columns from `inventory` (when a matching row is found in `invUpdate`,

```
  SELECT u.vin IS NOT NULL                     AS `update_found`
       , IF(u.vin IS NULL,i.vin    ,u.vin    ) AS `vin` 
       , IF(u.vin IS NULL,i.fee    ,u.fee    ) AS `fee`
       , IF(u.vin IS NULL,i.fi     ,u.fi     ) AS `fi`
       , IF(u.vin IS NULL,i.fo     ,u.fo     ) AS `fo`
       , IF(u.vin IS NULL,i.fum    ,u.fum    ) AS `fum`
       , u.updated_date                        AS `updated_date`
       , SUBSTRING(i.vin,1,5)                  AS `first_five`
    FROM inventory i
    LEFT
    JOIN invUpdate u
      ON u.vin = i.vin
    ORDER BY i.vin
```

Yes, that's a more complicated SQL statement. But I can test that. I can verify that it works properly, returns the set I need, separately from the rest of the program.  And that's going to make for a lot less code in my program.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

**Q:** lets say I have 32 columns in each table. If i want to show them all in this fashion, do I have to write IF(u.id IS NULL,i.col,u.col), for each column?

**A:** Unfortunately, yes.

But if I had 32 columns to contend with, I'd write a SQL statement to get me part of the SQL statement I needed... using SQL to generate SQL.

As a separate step (*not* as part of the program), from SQLyog of mysql command line client, or whatever...

I'd run a statement something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('     , IF(u.vin IS NULL,i.`', c.column_name, '`,u.`', c.column_name, '`) AS `', c.column_name, '`') AS stmt
  FROM information_schema.columns c
 WHERE c.table_name   = 'mytable'
   AND c.table_schema = 'mydb'
 ORDER BY c.ordinal_position
```

Substituting "mytable" and "mydb" with the table name and database name, and get back a result something like this:

```
stmt                                                                        
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     , IF(u.vin IS NULL,i.`id`,u.`id`) AS `id`                             
     , IF(u.vin IS NULL,i.`ext_name`,u.`ext_name`) AS `ext_name`           
     , IF(u.vin IS NULL,i.`src_name`,u.`src_name`) AS `src_name`           
     , IF(u.vin IS NULL,i.`database_id`,u.`database_id`) AS `database_id`  
     , IF(u.vin IS NULL,i.`protocol`,u.`protocol`) AS `protocol`           
     , IF(u.vin IS NULL,i.`location`,u.`location`) AS `location`           
     , IF(u.vin IS NULL,i.`device_name`,u.`device_name`) AS `device_name`  
     , IF(u.vin IS NULL,i.`vendor_name`,u.`vendor_name`) AS `vendor_name`  
     , IF(u.vin IS NULL,i.`model_name`,u.`model_name`) AS `model_name`
```

Then I would copy that result, and paste it into an editor, so I wouldn't have to type all those column names out.

Comment: thank you spencer. What if there are a lot of fields in the tables? is the only option to do this for every field?

Comment: No, it's not the only option. But does your query *really* need to return *all* of the columns in both tables? You could try `SELECT inventory.*, invUpdate.*`, and see what results you get. (I'm not sure if the first 'vin' gets assigned the column name 'vin', and the second one gets an automatic alias.) You can try swapping it around the other way `SELECT invUpdate.*, inventory.*`.  Or, `SELECT inventory.*, invUpdate.vin AS uvin, invUpdate.col2`. There's more than one way to skin a cat. My personal preference is to give an explicit list of just the expressions that are really needed.

Comment: With an explicit list of (qualified) expressions  in place of a **`*`**, BenHarold wouldn't be asking for table definitions. Right now, he doesn't know how many columns are being returned, or what the names of those columns are. And if does get the names, he still doesn't know which table which is from. He's got to go hunt in the database to get the table definitions, and figure out what the statement is returning. I prefer that BenHarold could see, from my SQL SELECT statement, *exactly* how many columns are returned, and *exactly* what the names of those columns are.

Comment: Yes I need all of the columns and No ultimately what I would like to do is select all records from inventory, if they exist in invUpdate I want the information from invUpdate to override the information in inventory. Basically if the end user updates a vehicle this info should supersede the information in the inventory table when displaying on the page.

Comment: You could do the "override" right in the SQL statement... `SELECT IF(u.id IS NULL,i.vin,u.vin) AS vin, IF(u.id IS NULL,i.col,u.col), ... FROM inventory i LEFT JOIN invUpdate u ON ...` and immensely simplify your code.

Comment: what is u.id representing here? That is what I am trying to accomplish, but I'm not sure I am at this level yet with my sql knowledge. I'm actually having a bit of trouble understanding your last breakdown?

Comment: `u` is a table alias I assigned to the invUpdate table in the statement. I assigned the alias `i` to the `inventory` table. That makes qualified references shorter. And `u.id` is a reference to the `id` column from `invUpdate`. What I want is to test whether a row was returned. A column that isn't NULL when a matching `invUpdate` row is found. A familiar pattern is for a non-NULL, unique, surrogate PRIMARY KEY for an entity table to be named `id`. The `IF()` is a MySQL function that evaluates the first argument as a boolean. If it's TRUE, return the 2nd argument, else return the 3rd argument.

Comment: I think I may have it working but just one more question. lets say I have 32 columns in each table. If i want to show them all in this fashion, do I have to write _IF(u.id IS NULL,i.col,u.col),_ for each column?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. But as a starting point, I would use SQL to help me generate the SQL I needed. MySQL has a database called `information_schema`, and in that is a table named `columns`, which has the column name of all of the tables in all of the databases. I'd write a query against `information_schema.columns` to get a list of columns. Since the pattern is going to be the same, I'd actually use an expression to generate the `IF(fee,fi.fo) AS fum` for me. The MySQL `CONCAT` function is very handy. I've updated my answer with another FOLLOWUP that shows an example.

Comment: This approach doesn't remove complexity, it just moves it to the SQL statement, instead of having to write a bunch of code that does the same thing. While someone looking at the program might not understand what the SQL statement is doing, at least they could take it out of the context of the program to test it, tweak it, etc. I'd do the same thing with a `SELECT * FROM` to see what that returns. (With the SELECT *, that reveals a lot less about what is being returned.) With my other statement, I can see how many columns and what the names of the columns are, just from the statement.

Comment: If I wanted to do the "overrides" in the code, I would still have the statement list out the columns in the SELECT list. I could use a query `from information_schema.columns` to get me the list of column names. I'd use a `CONCAT` to add the comma and add an alias for the columns   **`, foo AS upd_foo`**

Comment: Thank you again spencer for helping me out here. I believe it has helped me out quite a bit. Much appreciated, have a great night.

Answer (score 0):

As an entirely different approach... if the `inventory` and `invUpdate` have the same columns, column names, datatypes, etc. and what we want is to return all rows from `invUpdate` along with rows from `inventory` that don't have a matching row in `invUpdate`...

Then we could use an *anti-join* pattern to return the rows from `inventory`, and then combine that (using `UNION ALL`) with the rows from `invUpdate`.

Something like this:

```
 ( SELECT i.vin
        , i.col2
        , i.col3
     FROM inventory i 
     LEFT
     JOIN invUpdate iu
       ON iu.vin = i.vin
    WHERE iu.vin IS NULL
 ) 
 UNION ALL
 ( SELECT u.vin
        , u.col2
        , u.col3
     FROM invUpdate u
 )
 ORDER BY vin
```

The number of columns and the datatypes of the columns of the two queries (combined with UNION ALL) *must match*. (The column names aren't important, in terms of matching. The names of the columns in the resultset are derived from the *first* query.)

This answer doesn't specifically address the question that was asked; but I believe this is the resultset that OP is actually wanting.

As with the approach in my previous answer, this moves the complexity to the SQL statement, which greatly simplifies the code.

There are other SQL Patterns (other than the *anti-join*) that will return an equivalent result. For example, using a `NOT EXISTS` predicate. For example, the first query (before the `UNION ALL`) could also be written:

```
 ( SELECT i.vin
        , i.col2
        , i.col3
     FROM inventory i 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
          ( SELECT 1
              FROM invUpdate iu
             WHERE iu.vin = i.vin
          )
 )
 UNION ALL ...
```

(My preference is for the anti-join, unless I can get better performance out of another alternative, like a `NOT EXISTS (subquery)` or `NOT IN (subquery)`

Either way, with large sets, the absence of appropriate indexes will negatively impact performance.

Comment: I was originally trying a union all but was not clear as to how to add a JOIN OR NOT EXIST statement, having realized UNION ALL will give you everything from both tables. Thank you for your answers, they have helped me out tremendously in getting a better understanding of these complex query statements. Your explanations were thorough which makes a huge difference.

Comment: Just out of curiosity spencer, are you available to hire for contract work?